# SetInterval not repeating the function execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js structure like this:

```
var intervalID;

function counterUpdater(){
    intervalID = setInterval(ajax_counter_upload(),10000);  
}
function ajax_counter_upload(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "plan/counter.php",
        data: {tipo:'BP'},
        success: function(data){
            $("#spinner_msg").fadeTo(200,0.1,
                function(){
                    $(this).html(data);
                    $(this).fadeTo(900,1);
                });
        }
    });
}
function ajax_submit(){
    var submit_val=$("#stato").serialize();
    dest="plan/new_bp1.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: dest,
        data: submit_val,
        success: function(data){ 
            data1=data.split("|");
            if(data1[0]=="Successo"){ 
                $("#spnmsg").fadeTo(200,0.1,
                    function(){$(this).removeClass().addClass("spn_success").html(data1[1]).fadeTo(900,1)});
                }else if(data1[0]=="Errore"){
                    $("#spnmsg").fadeTo(200,0.1,
                    function(){$(this).removeClass().addClass("spn_error").html(data1[1]).fadeTo(900,1)});  
                }
        },
        complete: function(){
            clearInterval(intervalID);
            setTimeout(function(){ $('.container').load('plan/home.php');},2000); 
        }
    });
    setTimeout(function(){counterUpdater();},2000);
}
```

Goal would be to run counter_updater each 10 seconds when the ajax_submit starts and to stop it when the ajax_submit ends.

What I get now is to run counter_updater only once. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're not passing a callback to `setInterval`. Remove the parenthesis after `ajax_counter_upload`.

Comment: Explain goal in more detail. `ajax_submit` won't take 10 seconds

Comment: @charlietfl ajax_submit will take at least 4 or 5 minutes to perform. This second ajax call is triggered to show a progress next to the spinner

Comment: @tkausl you are right! This was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a mistake in your `setInterval` call: you have parentheses after the (intended) callback function name, which means that the function is actually called once and setInterval gets only the return value (nothing, in this case).

Simply remove the parentheses:

```
intervalID = setInterval(ajax_counter_upload, 10000);
//                                         ^^
```